# How to detect the format of the email being composed in an Outlook Add-in?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I saw that `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync()` would fail if called with `options.coercionType` set to `Office.CoercionType.Html` when the message body is in plain text.

I was wondering if there was any way to check what the format of the message body is before I called `setSelectedDataAsync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `getTypeAsync` method of the `body` object. Even more, this is suggested way to insert any data into the mail item's body. Before inserting, you should always first verify the supported item format by calling `getTypeAsync`. Please read more on the topic how to [Insert data in the body when composing an appointment or message in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/insert-data-in-the-body) in the Outlook API documentation.